# Logout redirect to home page

Tags: redirect, logout

I'm using custom menu for login/logout here below is my code:

```
<li>
      <?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  echo 'Welcome <strong><a href="http://kolkataonwheelsmagazine.com/wp-admin/index.php" >'.$user->user_firstname.'</a></strong>
  | <a  href="http://kolkataonwheelsmagazine.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&quot;">Logout</a>';
} else { ?>
  <strong><?php wp_loginout(); ?></strong>
  or <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php?action=register"> <strong>Register</strong></a>
<?php }?>
    </li>
```

but problem is :

redirect to login page not current page...

I want it should go to home page after logout.
Please help me...

Answer (score 27):

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');

function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
  wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
  exit;
}
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to modify logout and not login, then use [wp_logout_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url). Conversely you can use [wp_login_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) for just the login URL.

Example of an logout link:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

You can still use the function wp_loginout() but the redirect will work on both login and out. But if that is okay it could look like this:

```
<?php wp_loginout( home_url() ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanx Pontus,
I hv tried with your code...but its not workin it goes to 404.php page... It is my second post but it's not solved my problem... plz help me...

Comment: try `get_bloginfo('url')` in place of `home_url()`

Answer (score 3):

Pontus Abrahamsson is right, that is a legal code, but here is another one that I'm using in my theme.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('$index.php'); ?>">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Works for me with `'/'` for homepage, but not sure what `$` means here

Answer (score 1):

Since Wordpress `4.2.0` a logout hook filter was introduced `logout_redirect`.

> `apply_filters( 'logout_redirect', string $redirect_to, string $requested_redirect_to, WP_User $user )`
>
> Filters the log out redirect URL.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/logout_redirect/

| [Parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/logout_redirect/#parameters) | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `$redirect_to` | (`string`) The redirect destination URL. |
| `$requested_redirect_to` | (`string`) The requested redirect destination URL passed as a parameter. |
| `$user` | (`WP_User`) The `WP_User` object for the user that's logging out. |

---

### Simple use case scenario

```php
<?php
add_filter( 'logout_redirect', function() {
    return esc_url( home_url() );
} ); ?>
```

> *Anonymous functions used, PHP > `5.3`required*

---

### Learn more

- The same apply for logins, with a [`login_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/) introduced in `3.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress 4.2.0 you can just add:

```php
add_filter('logout_redirect', 'get_home_url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action('check_admin_referer', 'pfwp_logout_without_confirm', 10, 2);
function pfwp_logout_without_confirm($action, $result)
{
    /**
     * Allow logout without confirmation
     */
    if ($action == "log-out" && !isset($_GET['_wpnonce'])) {
        $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : get_permalink( wp_logout_url() )// or custom url;
        $location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url($redirect_to));
        header("Location: $location");
        die;
    }
}
```